# How can std::function's target be accessed?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I'm trying to compare the function pointer stored in two std::function objects, declared as `std::function<void(Args...)>` where `Args...` is a class template parameter. I intended to do this by comparing the output of target(), but I'm having trouble accessing that value. **What's the correct way access std::function::target()?**

Below is a boiled-down version of what I've tried:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename... Args>
void check(std::function<void(Args...)> func)
{
  auto type = func.target<void(*)(Args...)>();
}

void m() {}

int main()
{
  auto func = std::function<void()>(m);
  check<>(func);
}
```

And the output from compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 Demo.cpp`:

```
Demo.cpp: In function ‘void check(std::function<void(Args ...)>)’:
Demo.cpp:6:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
    6 |   auto type = func.target<void(Args...)>();
      |                           ^~~~
Demo.cpp:6:27: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘void’
```

Comment: The error show different code than what's in the example, but your issue is that you need to put `template` after `func.`: `func.template target<...>()`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target points out that `target` only has a value somtimes, but in this case it should have a value. It also mentions that it only exists after C++11, is your compiler set to C++11 mode?

Comment: You need to use `auto type = func.template target<void(*)(Args...)>();`. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: Can't say I've come across that particular syntax combination before, very interesting. Thanks!